# curl command not working on gitlab-ci pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am trying to pull a project ID using gitlab REST API v4, but when I issue the curl command, I get this error:

`"jobs:test:script config should be a string or an array of strings"`

The command is this one:

- `curl -k -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: PRIVATE-TOKEN" "https://gitlab.nbg992.poc.dcn.telekom.de/api/v4/projects?search=$CI_PROJECT_NAME"`

I tried to single quote it:

- `'curl -k -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: PRIVATE-TOKEN" "https://gitlab.nbg992.poc.dcn.telekom.de/api/v4/projects?search=$CI_PROJECT_NAME"'`

But when I do it, it removes the failure, but the command is ignored. 
So I tried to eval it like this:

- `eval - 'curl -k -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: PRIVATE-TOKEN" "https://gitlab.nbg992.poc.dcn.telekom.de/api/v4/projects?search=$CI_PROJECT_NAME"'`

When I do it, the failure its produced again:

`"jobs:test:script config should be a string or an array of strings"`

Any clue how should I issue the curl command? I think what is causing the failure is the colon within the `"PRIVATE-TOKEN: PRIVATE-TOKEN"`

Comment: This looks like an error coming up in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, can you share the full file?

Answer (score 1):

### This worked for me

Declare Job variables in variables sections eg:

- variables:

  - `PRIVATE-TOKEN: "TokenValue"`
  - `PRIVATE_HEADER: "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PRIVATE-TOKEN}"`

Then under Script Section of the CI file used Curl command as follows

- script:

  - `curl -k -H ${PRIVATE_HEADER} "https://gitlab.nbg992.poc.dcn.telekom.de/api/v4/projects?search=${CI_PROJECT_NAME}`

Using the `{}` braces around variable names made sure that `":"` issue doesn't show up